# Prolog: Finding the second largest element in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I know how to find the largest element of a list—no problem, but how should I go about finding the **second** largest element?

Say the predicate is `secondlargest(+List,?Val)` and succeeds if `Val` is the second largest element in the `List`.

If there is a tie for largest, then second largest is the same as largest...

Comment: This is *homework* -- http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yilan/324f09/324f09a5.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way of doing it O(n). First off, the starting predicate, (`slne/2`). Given we're after the 2nd largest element, we'll assume you have an input list (of numbers) with length  of at least two. Kick things off by comparing the relative values of the first two elements and record the current maximum and the current '2nd largest' (as suggested earlier, by Priyank), as arguments to a call to another predicate to do the work (`slne/4`):

```
slne([E0, E1|Es], Res) :-
    E0 > E1, !,
    slne(Es, E0, E1, Res).
slne([E0, E1|Es], Res) :-
    slne(Es, E1, E0, Res).
```

Secondly, now that we've got a starting point of reference, recurse through the remainder of the list (if any) and return the second largest element (SecMax), in (`slne/4`).

The base case: No more elements left! We're finished.

```
slne([], _, Res, Res).
```

The next case: we find a new local maximum at the start of the list:

```
slne([E|Es], Max, _SecMax, Res) :-
    E >= Max, !,
    slne(Es, E, Max, Res).
```

(Note that we threw away the current second largest (SecMax), because we assume that it was smaller than or equal to Max).

The next case: we don't find a new local maximum, but we do find a new '2nd best':

```
slne([E|Es], Max, SecMax, Res) :-
    E >= SecMax, !,
    slne(Es, Max, E, Res).
```

The last case: Throw away other values, as they're irrelevant - look at the rest instead:

```
slne([_|Es], Max, SecMax, Res) :-
    slne(Es, Max, SecMax, Res).
```

That's it. Personally, I like Juanjo's solution, mainly because it's 1 line of code, and the performance difference between O(n log n) and O(n) might be negligible in practice  even for large input. (Also note that `dsort/2` doesn't appear in all PROLOG implementations - e.g., in SWI-PL, you might try `msort/2` instead).

Comment: Clear. Solid. Steadfast... way to go!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you could do it using size-3  [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) in combination with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

zs_secondlargest([Z1,Z2|Zs], X) :-
   T1 #= max(Z1,Z2),
   T2 #= min(Z1,Z2),
   zs_secondlargest_(Zs, X, T1, T2).

zs_secondlargest_([], X, _, X).
zs_secondlargest_([Z|Zs], X, A1, A2) :-
   B2 #=     max(A2,Z),
   C1 #= max(min(A2,Z),A1),
   D1 #= max(C1,B2),
   D2 #= min(C1,B2),
   zs_secondlargest_(Zs, X, D1, D2).
```

Sample queries using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- zs_secondlargest([2,4,8,3,5,8,7], X).
X = 8 ? ;            %     8  >= 8
no
| ?- zs_secondlargest([6,4,3,6,3,4,8,6], X).
X = 6 ? ;            %             8>6
no
| ?- zs_secondlargest([2,3,5,4,1,6,7,3,9], X).
X = 7 ? ;            %             7 < 9
no
| ?- zs_secondlargest([2,3,5,4,1,6,7,3,9,8], X).
X = 8 ?              %                 9>8
yes
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my proposal for a clpfd variant of @sharky's version using [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159). Firstly, here is a reifying version of the *greater-equal to* relation using clpfd:

```
geq_to_t(X,Y,T) :-
   (X#>=Y) #<==> B,
   bool10_t(B,T).

bool10_t(1,true).
bool10_t(0,false).
```

With geq_to_t/3 and [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) the predicate can be defined like so:

```
% this corresponds to @sharky's slne/2:
sl_of(SL,[X1,X2|Xs]) :-
   if_(geq_to_t(X1,X2),
       max_sl_of_(X1,X2,Xs,SL),
       max_sl_of_(X2,X1,Xs,SL)).

% this corresponds to @sharky's slne/4:
max_sl_of_(_M,SL,[],SL).                 % base case
max_sl_of_(M,SL,[X|Xs],R) :-
   if_(geq_to_t(X,M),                    % if X#>=M
       max_sl_of_(X,M,Xs,R),             % X is new maximum
       if_(geq_to_t(X,SL),               % else if X#>=SL
           max_sl_of_(M,X,Xs,R),         % X is new 2nd largest
           max_sl_of_(M,SL,Xs,R))).      % else X is not of interest
```

Note that I flipped the order of the arguments in order to use a more desciptive naming (sl_of/2), so the list is now the second argument. As demanded in the bounty description, there are no useless choicepoints left if the second argument is ground:

```
   ?- sl_of(SL,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
SL = 5
   ?-
```

Samples from answer by @repeat:

```
   ?- sl_of(SL,[2,4,8,3,5,8,7]).
SL = 8
   ?- sl_of(SL,[6,4,3,6,3,4,8,6]).
SL = 6
   ?- sl_of(SL,[2,3,5,4,1,6,7,3,9]).
SL = 7
   ?- sl_of(SL,[2,3,5,4,1,6,7,3,9,8]).
SL = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about prolog but in general can't we store two variable, one for the highest and one for the second highest.

```
if(a >= x)
  b = a
  a = x
```

Comment: That's the imperative way. In prolog we use the declarive way.

Comment: Actually this is quite a sensible way to do this is Prolog, you just need to translate it into a declarative style. In this case that would be a recursive predicate that scans the list keeping track of the two largest elements seen so far. An algorithm is just an abstract method for solving a problem and can usually be implemented in any programming paradigm. Like any language, preferred coding styles are often quite subjective. Sometimes in Prolog it is convenient to use a rather un-declarative approach, such as failure-driven loops.

Comment: I second you Humble coffee. This answer just gave a hint as to how you can solve this problem. And as you said it is possible to keep track of the largest elements in each pass. 

@Juanjo Again there is no such thing as Imperative or Declarative Algorithm. An Algorithm is an Algorithm is an Algorithm

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you two different algorithms. First one is easy, the second one is a bit tricky.

1. Write a Merge Sort function(Descending order), then just pick the second element. This is easy but it takes O(nlogn) time.
2. In general for any k you can solve this by the following algorithm. This runs in linear time.

--Break the list into group of five elements
--Find the median of each group, which can be done with a fixed number of comparisons
--Recursively find medians or medians
--Partition the original List wrt medians of medians
--Recursively find the kth largest element in the appropriate smaller list.

You can find a more detailed discussion on this algorithm in "Introduction To Algorithms by Cormen" Chapter -9

I would recommend you too try implementing it on your own without seeing any existing implementation. I had a lot of fun implementing this algorithm in prolog :)

Comment: That's the imperative way. In prolog we use the declarive way.

Comment: Algorithm is independent of paradigms. Its just the way to solve a problem. I just gave an idea how to go about and solve the problem instead of just copy pasting my code. If you still dont believe me ..I will post my implementation of this Algorithm in Prolog.

Comment: And please be descriptive while Down voting. There is no such thing as Prolog Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idiom to be used in any language:

Loop over the list, count each element and insert into another list data to tell you the element, and it's size. Sort the list in descending order. Move the list pointer to the 2nd element. You have the 2nd largest element now.

Comment: That's the imperative way. In prolog we use the declarive way.

Comment: Depends on if you chose to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 1):

First task: implement a sort predicate, if that's beyond your capabilities right now, look in Clocksin and Mellish.

Second task: write a predicate which selects the head of the tail of a list.  Apply this predicate to your sorted list.

OR, since you already know how to select the largest element in a list, write a predicate to drop the largest element of a list, and apply your existing predicate to the remainder of the original list.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it in Prolog:

```
secondLargest(L, Y) :- dsort(L, [X,Y|T])
```

Where dsort works like this:

```
?- dsort([2,3,4,2,1], L).
L = [4,3,2,2,1]
```

You can implement dsort by your own, the hacky part is how I wrote the list [X,Y|T]. That's read: the list is made of 2 elements (X and Y) and a tail (T).

Comment: That works, but it's not optimal. Assuming `dsort` is a comparison sort, it's `O(n log n)`, but there's a simple `O(n)` algorithm that solves the problem in question.

Comment: You can use predsort/3 in SWI-Prolog, with the following closure: revcompare(R,X,Y) :- compare(R,Y,X). i.e. ?- predsort(revcompare,[2,3,4,2,1],L) gives L = [4, 3, 2, 1].

Answer (score 1):

another (not the best obviously) approach would be as follows:
1. find max element in list L
2. remove max element from list L and get new list L1
3. find max in L1 and return it

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes dsort doesn't work in some versions of SWI-Prolog like mine. 
So, This is the simplest code:

```
secondLargest(List,X):-
        msort(List,SortedList),reverse(SortedList,[_|[X|_]]).
```

Comment: Somewhat works, but is not portable and non-monotonic: breaks down with insufficient instantiation. Consider `?- Zs = [_,_,_], secondLargest(Zs,X), Zs = [3,1,2].` which gives `X = 1` as the only answer. `X = 2` would be better...

Comment: not sure why you used  
Zs = [_,_,_], secondLargest(Zs,X), Zs = [3,1,2].
and didn't use 
secondLargest(Zs,X), Zs = [3,1,2].

Comment: The one you specify throws an exception, the other one does not (but gives a wrong answer).